# Gitlab: Unable to clone by http (cloning by ssh works well)

Tags: git, gitlab, git-clone

I'm running Gitlab 5.4 and recently tried to do a git clone by http from my server. I found out that it doesn't work even though cloning by ssh works well.

Here is the error:

```
git clone http://myservername/gitlab/myrepo.git
Cloning into '<repo>'...
remote: Not Found
fatal: repository 'http://<myservername>/gitlab/<repo>.git/' not found
```

And here is the production.log output (no errors produced)

```
Started GET "/gitlab/<repo>.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack" for xx.xx.xx.xx at 2013-08-13 02:24:46 +0000
```

More info of this issue here... [gitlabhq Issue#4766](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4766)

Answer (score 1):

i guess its the firewall maybe? but the web server also should be running.

what do you get on requesting the url with the browser?

Answer (score 1):

As the [OP kbaylosis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1554360/kbaylosis) mentions in [GitLab issue 4766](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4766#issuecomment-23107668):

> It works well now in 6.0.

So whatever the issue was, it has been fixed between 5.x and 6.x.